# VLC how to get the full path of currently playing video

Tags: windows, windows-10, vlc-media-player

I have a video playing in vlc on windows. I just need to grab the full path of the video file on my hard disk that is currently playing. How do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Playlist view, open View > Playlist Table Columns, and turn on URI. That should give you an extra column which will show you where the video is playing from.

Comment: Not sure why vlc made it so hard to view a file's path

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Tools** > **Media Information** > **Location** or
press **(ctrl+i)** > **Location** while playing any video.

Answer (score 0):

Right in the Playlist window, the contextual menu of each item has a "Show containing folder…" option